# filter struct objects from object element containing array of string

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined a struct as follows :

```
struct ECUnifiedStructure{

var contactName             : String!
var contactNumber           = [String]()
...
...

init(contact: CNContact , EProfile : Bool) {
    let validTypes = [
        CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone,
        CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile,
        CNLabelPhoneNumberMain,
        CNLabelHome,
        CNLabelWork
    ]

    var givenName           = contact.givenName + " " + contact.middleName
    let familyName          = contact.familyName
    if (givenName == "" && familyName == "") || givenName == " "{
        givenName           = contact.organizationName
    }

    self.contactName = givenName.capitalized + familyName.capitalized
    self.contactNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.compactMap({ (PhoneNumber) -> String? in
        if let phoneLabel  = PhoneNumber.label , validTypes.contains(phoneLabel){
            return PhoneNumber.value.stringValue.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        }
        return nil
    })
....
....
....
}}
```

**Problem Statement :** Need to filter an array of ECUnifiedStructure (ie . [ECUnifiedStructure]) based upon name and phone Number(check both substring and string as whole).

**Current Implementation :** The following is the current implementation I have done. Here both contacts and filter contacts are [ECUnifiedStructure].

```
self.filterContacts = self.contacts.filter {($0.contactName).range(of: textString, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil} + self.contacts.filter {($0.contactNumber.compactMap {$0}.contains(textString))}
```

**Issues with implementation :** Getting result for filtering contact name as intended with results including both string as whole and substrings but

> *when filtering phone number , result for substrings not* *found . Only when we give whole phone number does the result turn up.*

Probable cause :

```
self.contacts.filter {($0.contactNumber.compactMap {$0}.contains(textString))}
```

> Eg : Suppose contacts = [[name: "David" , phoneNumber :
>   ["1234567890",9876543210]], [name: "Hilton" , phoneNumber :
>   ["1011111111","2222222222"]] , [name: "lewis" , phoneNumber :
>   ["1111111111","2222222222"]]]

searchString = "10"

> intended result = [[name: "David" , phoneNumber :
>   ["1234567890",9876543210]], [name: "Hilton" , phoneNumber :
>   ["1011111111","2222222222"]]]

current Result = empty.

Please propose an elegant way of doing it.If you can please point out what I did wrong . Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, I have tried it. @ArashEtemad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return any struct object that has a phonenumber containing "10"

```
let result = contacts.filter{ $0.phoneNumber.contains(where: { $0.contains("10")}) }
```

Using your original filter code

```
self.filterContacts = self.contacts.filter {($0.contactName).range(of: textString, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil} + self.contacts.filter { $0.contactNumber.contains(where: {$0.contains(textString)})}
```

---

Here is my complete test code

```
struct ECUnifiedStructure{
    var name          : String!
    var phoneNumber   = [String]()
}

let contacts:[ECUnifiedStructure] = [ECUnifiedStructure(name: "David" , phoneNumber : ["1234567890","9876543210"]), 
     ECUnifiedStructure(name: "Hilton" , phoneNumber : ["1011111111","2222222222"]) , 
     ECUnifiedStructure(name: "lewis" , phoneNumber : ["1111111111","2222222222"])]

let result = contacts.filter{ $0.phoneNumber.contains(where: { $0.contains("10")}) }

for r in result {
    print(r)
}
```

output

```
ECUnifiedStructure(name: Optional("David"), phoneNumber: ["1234567890", "9876543210"])
ECUnifiedStructure(name: Optional("Hilton"), phoneNumber: ["1011111111", "2222222222"])
```